Weird behavior when updating the values using `iloc` in pandas dataframe
While copying a pandas dataframe, ideally, we should use .copy(), which is a deep copy by default.
We could also achieve the same using new_df = pd.Dataframe(old_df), which is also intuitive (and common style across most programming languages since in principle, we are calling a copy constructor).
In both cases, they have different memory identifers as shown below. But when I change the old_df using .iloc, it changes the value for the new_df. Is this the expected behaviour? I couldn't figure out this behaviour using the docs. Am I missing something trivial?
# ! pip install smartprint

from smartprint import smartprint as sprint
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}
original_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(original_df)
original_df['A'] = original_df['A'].apply(lambda x: x * 1000)

print ("============ Changing a column with pd.Dataframe(old_df); No change")
sprint(original_df)
sprint(new_df)
sprint (id(new_df), id(original_df))



data = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}
original_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(original_df)

original_df.iloc[0,:] = 20

print ("============ Using .iloc with pd.Dataframe(old_df); Change")
sprint(original_df)
sprint(new_df)
sprint (id(new_df), id(original_df))



data = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}
original_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
new_df = original_df.copy()

original_df.iloc[0,:] = 20

print ("============ Using .iloc with old_df.copy(); No change")
sprint(original_df)
sprint(new_df)
sprint (id(new_df), id(original_df))

Output:
============ Changing a column with pd.Dataframe(old_df); No change
original_df :       A  B
0  1000  4
1  2000  5
2  3000  6
new_df :    A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
id(new_df), id(original_df) : 140529132556544 140529514510944
============ Using .iloc with pd.Dataframe(old_df); Change
original_df :     A   B
0  20  20
1   2   5
2   3   6
new_df :     A   B
0  20  20
1   2   5
2   3   6
id(new_df), id(original_df) : 140528893052000 140528894065584
============ Using .iloc with old_df.copy(); No change
original_df :     A   B
0  20  20
1   2   5
2   3   6
new_df :    A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
id(new_df), id(original_df) : 140529057828336 140528940223984

My python and pandas versions are listed below:
import sys
sys.version
Out[16]: '3.8.17 (default, Jul  5 2023, 16:18:40) \n[Clang 14.0.6 ]'
pd.__version__
Out[17]: '1.4.3'


This is the expected behavior of DataFrame, it is also happening when you're passing a numpy array as input:
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
a[0][0] = 9

print(df)
    0  1
0  99  2
1   3  4

It is actually well described in the DataFrame documentation:

copy: bool or None, default None
Copy data from inputs. For dict data, the default of None behaves like copy=True. For DataFrame or 2d ndarray input, the default of None
behaves like copy=False. If data is a dict containing one or more
Series (possibly of different dtypes), copy=False will ensure that
these inputs are not copied.

a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

df = pd.DataFrame(a, copy=True)
a[0][0] = 99

print(df)
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4

what about changing a full column?
In this case you don't mutate the column but overwrite it with a new one. This means that the underlying objects are now different:
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

df[0] = 99

print(a)
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]


Now this makes sense the way you explain it. Still I find it counterintuitive, but that is just the ex- java developer in me thinking :)  marking as accepted.
